# I'm wondering how this is possible? Discord bot

Tags: discord, bots

I recently receive a 2 message in discord with invite link to server I received it from bot who doesn't share the same server with me or anything

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

How this is possible, I find some py codes but only work if the user and bot share same server

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, Greedy
from discord import User

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def pm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
    for user in users:
        await user.send(message)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

How can I make one send messages to list of IDs not in same server?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the bot left the server after he sent the invite to everyone.

You could check if one of the bots was in the servers in the audit-log.

Comment: I've never been on a shared server with this 2 bots

Answer (score 0):

you could either get the user by id with the `guild.get_member(id)`. That requires the user to be on that specific guild you try to get the user.
Or you can use `bot.get_user(id) / await bot.fetch_user(id)`. There the bot tries to get the user. If found you can do sth with it else it will return None or raises the command Error UserNotFound.
A bot that has no mutal guild with a specific user cannot send a dm to them.

Also what purpuse is it to send dms to multiple users from a list?
Keep in mind that its against the [Discord TOS](https://discord.com/terms) to mass dm users without permissions. If they did not opt in sth to get dms I would not send random dms do multiple users.